# Get the FirstEntryDate and its related SalaryPackage information

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query returning the Salary Package information for an EmployeeId=4509 :

```
SELECT SalaryPackageId,
StartDate
FROM SalaryPackage.SalaryPackage 
WHERE EmployeeId = 4509 AND IsDisabled = 0 AND StatusId IN (1,2)
ORDER BY StartDate;
```

The result is like below :

```
SalaryPackageId StartDate
7964            2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
12138           2015-09-14 00:00:00.0000000
11763           2015-10-01 00:00:00.0000000
15498           2016-10-01 00:00:00.0000000
19186           2017-04-01 00:00:00.0000000
23254           2017-10-01 00:00:00.0000000
33821           2018-09-14 00:00:00.0000000
44478           2019-09-14 00:00:00.0000000
```

The First Entry Date is defined as the date of the first Salary Package with the minimum date which is for EmployeeId=4509 :

```
SalaryPackageId StartDate
7964            2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
```

I want to get the SalaryPackageId for each employee with the FirstEntryDate like below :

```
SELECT  EmployeeId,
SalaryPackageId,
MIN(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId) AS FirstEntryDate
FROM SalaryPackage.SalaryPackage 
WHERE EmployeeId = 4509 AND IsDisabled = 0 AND StatusId IN (1,2)
```

But I get duplicate results like below (for EmployeeId=4509) :

```
EmployeeId  SalaryPackageId FirstEntryDate
4509        7964            2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
4509        12138           2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
4509        11763           2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
4509        15498           2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
4509        19186           2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
4509        23254           2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
4509        33821           2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
4509        44478           2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
```

The expected output is

```
EmployeeId  SalaryPackageId FirstEntryDate
4509        7964            2015-02-23 00:00:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  EmployeeId,SalaryPackageId,StartDate,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY FirstEntryDate, SalaryPackageId) AS rn
  FROM SalaryPackage.SalaryPackage 
  WHERE EmployeeId = 4509 AND IsDisabled = 0 AND StatusId IN (1,2)
        -- here EmployeeId should be removed
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```